# How to get started with Aurelia UX

Tags: aurelia

So, i'm trying to get aurelia-ux to work but am unable to.

There is a demo application, but that one is based on 0.3 while 0.6.1 exists. And it seems quite some stuff changed.

The latest npm package for aurelia-ux that exists is 0.3.0, so I guess that is not the one to use. A package aurelia-ux/components seems the one to use.. for that one exists a 0.6.1 package.

So I added to my package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
      "@aurelia-ux/components": "^0.6.1",
```

And to my aurelia.json:

```
      {
        "name": "aurelia-ux",
        "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/components/dist/amd",
        "main": "index",
        "resources": ["**/*.{css,html}"]
      }
```

And this gives me this in my build output:

```
Tracing aurelia-ux...
 ------- File not found or not accessible ------
| Location: C:/Work/Dat/AuFront/src/@aurelia-ux/button.js|
| Requested by: C:\Work\Dat\AuFront\node_modules\@aurelia-ux\components\dist\amd\index.js
| Is this a package? Make sure that it is configured in aurelia.json and that it is not a Node.js package
```

So this looks like some kind of path reference problem? Is there someone with a working example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, the trick is to include this npm package:

> @aurelia-ux/components

And in the Aurelia.json add this:

```
     {
        "name": "@aurelia-ux/core",
        "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/core/dist/amd",
        "main": "index",
        "resources": ["**/*.{css,html}"]
      },
```

And then **every** component you want to use, like so:

```
      {
        "name": "@aurelia-ux/button",
        "path": "../node_modules/@aurelia-ux/button/dist/amd",
        "main": "index",
        "resources": ["**/*.{css,html}"]
      },
```

Then, use it on your main.ts like this:

```
    .plugin('@aurelia-ux/core')
    .plugin('@aurelia-ux/button')
```